# .Net 6 Core web application won't start on Windows Server 2022 using IIS10

Tags: c#, .net, publish, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I am trying to publish and get running a .NET Core 6 web application on Windows Server 2022 using IIS10.
The application published to the correct directory, and when I try to run it on the Server, it gives me an error HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start.
.NET 6 x64 is the only framework installed on the server as I know having 64-bit and 32-bit present can cause a problem.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\TSSPortal.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I'm sure that this will spawn further questions, so I will monitor the thread.

```
                ********** UPDATE ***********
```

A suggestion was made on another thread to run it from the command line. When I do that (run the .exe), it comes back and says it's listening on port 5000.
When I go to the browser and type in http://localhost:5000, the app runs and connects to the remote database.

Any suggestions as to what that might point to?

Comment: Sounds like an uncaught Exception is being thrown during startup. Have you tried debugging the aplication or logging any errors?

Comment: You can always determine the reason by checking the following sources: `stdout`, `Event Viewer`, or the [IIS logging directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/managing-iis-log-file-storage).

Comment: Run a report to rule out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html and then open Windows application event log to learn more about the remaining errors.

Comment: Check whether the attribute value of hostingModel in the configuration file is OutOfProcess. If the value of the hostingModel property is InProcess, try to change it to OutOfProcess and start the project again.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below steps:

1. Check the Event Viewer logs under 'Application'.
2. Verify that the .NET 6 runtime version matches with the one used to develop the application.
3. Check the permissions given to the user account thats running the application pool on ISS.
4. Set the  element's stdoutLogEnabled attribute to true.

These might help you get closer to the real issue.

Cheers!